Polyphase full-bridge rectifier formula
I am learning circuit analysis/design as an hobby, and I came across this circuit schematic while practicing. The phase differences between AC sources are 120 degrees.

I am using the three phase full-bridge rectifier formula when K1 switch is on to convert AC sources into an approximate DC source.

But I don't know what to do when K1 is off. Is there a similar two phase full-bridge rectifier formula? Or what other methods can I use to analyze this circuit?

Simulators are free and accurate and something that once learnt, will be a bonus for many EE things you do in the future.

Like Andy said in his comment, simulation is a powerful tool, and in this case the answer becomes obvious.
A few things to get straight first:

Vdc in your formula is the average voltage and assumes no peak holding by capacitors.

Vs in your formula is the peak phase voltage.

CircuitLab and probably other simulators use a peak value for the sine amplitude.

A simulator needs a ground somewhere; I chose the input side.


Using some real values:
VphaseRMS = 120 V
VphasePeak = 169.7 V
VlineRMS = VphasePeak * sqrt(3) = 208 V
VlinePeak = 294.1 V
For all three phases:
VrectifiedAvg = VphasePeak * 1.65 = 280 V

With one phase missing, it will default to a one-phase system:
VrectifiedAvg = VlinePeak * 2/Pi = 294.1 * 0.6366 = 187.2 V
2/Pi is the average to peak ratio, you can look that up, or integrate over a half of a sine wave.
Or in terms of VphasePeak:
VrectifiedAvg = VPhasePeak * Sqrt(3) * 2/Pi


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Some references:
3 Phase line-line and phase
3 Phase Rectified
