Three phase rectifier output current
I´m designing a three phase power transformer, and i´m having troubles with the choosing the current value. After the transformer, goes through a three phase bridge rectifier ( full wave and not controlled ). I know that the output current of the rectifier has to be 100A maximum ( resistive load ). How should I calculate the Line current? or Phase current if it´s a delta secondary? For not making more mistakes, can you answer the same about voltage?

Draw a schematic and phase diagram. Some of what you need is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/715630/polyphase-full-bridge-rectifier-formula/715643#715643

(Why would a resistive load benefit from DC? Is this for load sharing? What about harmonics?)
